# Redirection not working properly.It Reload the page continuously

Tags: reactjs, mobx-react

I have given the redirection like as follows in the APIClient.ts file and it reload the page every second not stable.

```
if (res.status >= 400) {
window.location.assign('/errorcode');
const serverError = new Error(error) as ICustomServerError;
serverError.res = res;
throw serverError;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear. You are simply redirecting. There's something else going on.

Comment: What's lib you using connect to graphql? (fetch, axios..)

Comment: I am using axios.

Comment: Could you provide more of the code around your current snippet? For example what the api-call looks like or when this call is made.

Comment: common api call is happening , behind scene websocket and one request is always generates 401, that's why it comes in that call and continuously redirecting.

Comment: Please provide the complete code of your api request.